# What's the difference between decoderawtransaction and decodescript?

Tags: transactions, script, bitcoin-cli

I'm looking for an explanation on the difference between the bitcoin CLI for `decoderawtransaction` and `decodescript` please.

From what I know, `decodetransaction` will undo the hash and ECDSA elliptic curve calculations for the overall transaction data, and break it down into asm, hex, reqSigs, type of script & the original address. How is this different from `decodescript` & when should I be using one vs the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Bitcoin protocol has its own serialization format for transactions, blocks, scripts etc. These formats optimize for space, which means they aren't particularly human-readable, so there are bitcoin-cli commands that can be used to decode them into a more human-readable form.

Consider the transaction [60267bfd9494e1a6a5218184c36bf4c97adccbbde40487a2f92fcfffc10d0500](https://mempool.space/tx/60267bfd9494e1a6a5218184c36bf4c97adccbbde40487a2f92fcfffc10d0500). Here is its serialization in hexadecimal:

`010000000001018154f1677366e5799f61646e5cea1ea13ef23c0bd3ba4cc845dcdc3f061c47570100000000ffffffff01035a28000000000016001486918c31af903a4c7ed2dc8191156c0ef44a11b40141f33812c31e4c1ae9a46c55e1463121d42c1c5cd64afc86fe94d2a126b2e515823954b079e11bf1251aa9d585cf4a83a0473634f1c22891249dacf9f93c976ff40100000000`

When you feed this into `decoderawtransaction`, you get this:

```
{
  "txid": "60267bfd9494e1a6a5218184c36bf4c97adccbbde40487a2f92fcfffc10d0500",
  "hash": "9aab2076ba5b8f2656d1a2b9f9928c6cb6a4d6f607ef88589ea6b6e842f3f320",
  "version": 1,
  "size": 151,
  "vsize": 100,
  "weight": 397,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "57471c063fdcdc45c84cbad30b3cf23ea11eea5c6e64619f79e5667367f15481",
      "vout": 1,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "",
        "hex": ""
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "f33812c31e4c1ae9a46c55e1463121d42c1c5cd64afc86fe94d2a126b2e515823954b079e11bf1251aa9d585cf4a83a0473634f1c22891249dacf9f93c976ff401"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.02644483,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "0 86918c31af903a4c7ed2dc8191156c0ef44a11b4",
        "desc": "addr(bc1qs6gccvd0jqayclkjmjqez9tvpm6y5yd5azp9qs)#h6rkqret",
        "hex": "001486918c31af903a4c7ed2dc8191156c0ef44a11b4",
        "address": "bc1qs6gccvd0jqayclkjmjqez9tvpm6y5yd5azp9qs",
        "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Among many other things, this also decodes the transaction's output scripts (under `scriptPubKey`). However, if you have a serialized script outside the context of a transaction, which in this case would be `001486918c31af903a4c7ed2dc8191156c0ef44a11b4`, you can use `decodescript` on it:

```
{
  "asm": "0 86918c31af903a4c7ed2dc8191156c0ef44a11b4",
  "desc": "addr(bc1qs6gccvd0jqayclkjmjqez9tvpm6y5yd5azp9qs)#h6rkqret",
  "address": "bc1qs6gccvd0jqayclkjmjqez9tvpm6y5yd5azp9qs",
  "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
  "p2sh": "3Np3NnSFbrdMjRi9ECcnoWCfHBPVVHe5iw"
}
```

Additionally, there are scripts that `decoderawtransaction` won't decode, for example redeem scripts in witnesses of P2WSH inputs.

Take transaction [b4bb98f79c50ef7fe74fb9fac705e3952650161477bd82b2687c953b71a44594](https://mempool.space/tx/b4bb98f79c50ef7fe74fb9fac705e3952650161477bd82b2687c953b71a44594) which spends one P2WSH input with a 2-of-3 multisignature script. The serialized script will be given by `decoderawtransaction` as the last item of `txinwitness`:

`5221020fc49e0380f0ba7d849609e746e36557d1ad457cb88888a73fdbd9a7d7ab3b6a210211bcd0fc487c5ed1c60adb5379c9b078874b4e525a4df2c27540c9db856760082102e8033bc9956afcd3abba9cfe0817ab16c5ec84e2f8edc1da4373bac54dacf57253ae`

Decoded by `decodescript` as:

```
{
  "asm": "2 020fc49e0380f0ba7d849609e746e36557d1ad457cb88888a73fdbd9a7d7ab3b6a 0211bcd0fc487c5ed1c60adb5379c9b078874b4e525a4df2c27540c9db85676008 02e8033bc9956afcd3abba9cfe0817ab16c5ec84e2f8edc1da4373bac54dacf572 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
  "desc": "multi(2,020fc49e0380f0ba7d849609e746e36557d1ad457cb88888a73fdbd9a7d7ab3b6a,0211bcd0fc487c5ed1c60adb5379c9b078874b4e525a4df2c27540c9db85676008,02e8033bc9956afcd3abba9cfe0817ab16c5ec84e2f8edc1da4373bac54dacf572)#d63cpu6r",
  "type": "multisig",
  "p2sh": "37CYRhHBjdgoTC7KQpUuTH3zAcm9akWqAd",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 ec21a1b4e8cdaa89737895168ead0c3210fc2d1c6bf9805e45a475f714c75140",
    "desc": "addr(bc1qass6rd8gek4gjumcj5tgatgvxgg0ctgud0ucqhj9536lw9x829qqpnu64e)#2wsw9unx",
    "hex": "0020ec21a1b4e8cdaa89737895168ead0c3210fc2d1c6bf9805e45a475f714c75140",
    "address": "bc1qass6rd8gek4gjumcj5tgatgvxgg0ctgud0ucqhj9536lw9x829qqpnu64e",
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "p2sh-segwit": "3PCgTmZsCjK6KHJeEHJ7iCjVPqb3ygf5jF"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! Could decodescript do everything which decoderawtransaction is able to? (I'd like to further understand when to use each of them appropriately). Would also like to know more examples for decodescript use cases please. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, a transaction consists of a lot more than just scripts, so `decodescript` cannot do everything. I added an example of a P2WSH script.

Comment: Sorry, how did you acquire `5221020fc49e0380f0ba7d849609e746e36557d1ad457cb88888a73fdbd9a7d7ab3b6a210211bcd0fc487c5ed1c60adb5379c9b078874b4e525a4df2c27540c9db856760082102e8033bc9956afcd3abba9cfe0817ab16c5ec84e2f8edc1da4373bac54dacf57253ae`?

Comment: Is `decodescript` typically used to decode ScriptPubKey & ScriptSig as well?